# How to change Tab Focus order in Tableau Dashboards to ensure compliance with Accessibility Guidelines?

Tags: python, accessibility, dashboard, tableau-desktop, tab-ordering

Tableau dashboards need to follow accessibility guidelines. Fixing the 'Tab' focus order is one of the main challenges that most Tableau developers face while ensuring that the focus order is set in the desired left to right, top to bottom format. However, most of the time the focus order moves in the order in which the elements were added on Tableau dashboards creating a need to manually fix the issue as described [here](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6USYSA3/how-can-i-set-the-focus-order-of-the-views-and-objects-in-a-dashboard).

How do we automate the same?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach**

1. Read the '.twb' file into Jupyter notebook using parse function of xml.etree.ElementTree library.
2. Find the root node & retrieve all the zone tags present in the .twb file using the same.
3. Save the total occurrences of ids present in the .twb file. This will help in understanding how many consecutive ids numbers need to be created.
4. Replace the existing ids with consecutive id number using loop.

For the step by step code, please refer to my Github Repository [here](https://github.com/Pritha01/Tableau-Focus-Order-Fix)

This Python code will help you to update the zone tag ids automatically without having to use manual effort. Thanks to Kelly Gupton for sharing the 'Dashboard Focus Order.twb' [(here)](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C6USYSA3/how-can-i-set-the-focus-order-of-the-views-and-objects-in-a-dashboard) using which I have been able to test the code.